# How to I get a username from a network (Windows)?

Tags: java, windows, file, networking

I have been using the `Files.getOwner()` to try and make a log of folders being made on a network however doing so returns an id as below.

`S-1-5-21-1027050117-121514058-1707179805-77926 (Unknown)`

What would be the best way to get the login name of the owner instead of the id above?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `System.getProperty("user.name");` This will return the environment variable `USERNAME`.

Comment: I am talking about the username of the folder/ file owner, not the username of the system the program is run on.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 with JDK 8 when I run the following Java code

```
System.out.println(Files.getOwner(Paths.get("C:\\test\\test.txt")));
```

on a text file I just created, I get the following output:

```
chris-PC\chris_2 (User)
```

Where chris-PC is my computer name and chris_2 is my Windows user account. When I googled this problem I found [this post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/598314/Java/java/Java-API-Files-getowner-returns) where someone has the same issue as you with a samba mapped drive. The response given there is as follows:

> As far as I know, this is an internal user ID which Windows displays when it cannot - for >some reason - translate it to the real user name.
>
> I don't know how Samba provides file and folder owners to Windows, but
>   I'd say that Windows are unable to find that user. That user exists on
>   unix, it probably doesn't have any relationship to the Windows machine
>   accessing the share. You'd probably have to set both systems in a way
>   which would allow them to share user definitions (eg. put them both to
>   a Windows domain) to be able to display the user name on Windows.
>   (Just guessing.)

So, I'm not sure if this problem can be reasonably solved.